# unable to connect to flask docker image

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile

I'm a beginner in docker and I have a folder called `MovieFlix` that contains a `flask web service` app with some `html templates` that I `connect to a mongodb image from docker` . I want to run my flask app as a docker image . For that I have succesfully created a `DockerFile` which I list below :

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER bill <bill@gmailcom>
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip 
RUN pip3 install flask pymongo flask_bcrypt 
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR "/MovieFlix"
COPY webservice.py . //copy the flask app i want to run 
COPY templates . //copy my html templates
CMD ["python3", "webservice.py", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

My image is built succesfully however when I run `docker -p 5000:80 flask(my image name )`
and copy the url `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` in my search engine I get that `the page does not work and 127.0.0.1 did not send data`  I can run my `webservice.py` normally on vscode and the mongodb image is running so I do not think the problem is there and I run my flask app with

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

I would appreciate your help with guiding me to solve this issue .  Thank you in advance .

Comment: `app.run(host='127.0.0.1')` will be inaccessible from outside the container.  You need to set that to `0.0.0.0`, or parse out the `--host` command-line option.

Comment: @DavidMaze you mean to delete it and my port from the dockerfile ?

Comment: @DavidMaze I changed my host to 0.0.0.0 and I still could not connect . I got that the web page must have permanently moved to another address or could not be working